# did in i need in my c++ code to use vectors or learn STL

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

i need to initialize my code during runtime the program is searching for how many times is the number in multiplication table

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 0, n = 1 , count=0 ;
    
    cin >> n>>x;
        int arr[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i <n-1 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <n-1 ; j++) {
 
            cin >>  arr[i][j];
            
            if(arr[i][j]==x)count++;
 
        }
 
        }
        cout<<count;
 
    }
```

because i am getting error

Comment: Yes, use a vector.  run time sized array == `std::vector`.

Comment: The C++ standard library (the term STL is anachronistic) *is* part of C++.

Comment: you can dynamically allocate your array using runtime size but u will have to manage the memory. `std::vector` does all of that for you

Comment: Which error did you get? Compilation error? Run time error ? Please provide details. Note that here, you are only reading (n-1)*(n-1) numbers

Comment: `int arr[n][n];` is a variable-length array and not supported by standard C++. It's supported by some (at least one) compilers with a compiler extension. You should avoid such extensions but sometimes it's good to know that these exist. Use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by *multiplication table* you mean to say *matrix*.

For this particular problem you don't need even the matrix. You can just do by using a temporary variable. Something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int n, x, count = 0, tmep;
    std::cin >> n >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            std::cin >> temp;
            if (temp == x) ++count;
        }
    std::cout << count;
}
```

You aren't getting proper answer probably because you are not reading the complete matrix. Your loops run from `i = 0` to `i < n - 1` (same for `j`). You need to either change `<` to `<=` or `n - 1` to `n`.

If you need to re-use the inputted matrix, then probably an approach like this will be good:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n, x, count = 0;
    std::cin >> n >> x;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat(n, std::vector<int>(n));
    for (auto &row : mat)
        for (auto &ele : row) {
            std::cin >> ele;
            if (ele == x) ++count;
        }
    std::cout << count;
}
```

In any case something like `arr[n][n]` is not recommended as variable-length arrays are not supported by the standard itself, although some compilers like `g++` do so.

Answer (score 2):

> did in i need in my c++ code to use vectors or learn STL?

The answer depends on your objective.

If you want to accomplish a programming task at hand in the most expedient manner, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

If you want to learn how to manage allocation and dealloction of dynamic memory, learn about [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) and use them instead of `int arr[n][n];`